# How do I retrieve the role and permissions from the MongoDB user model?

Tags: mongodb, express, types, nosql

```
const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String },
        email: { type: String, required: true },
        phone: { countryCode: { type: String }, number: { type: String } },
        role: {
            ref_id: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: roleModel },
            name: { type: String }
        }
}

const RoleSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        permissions: [{ type: String, required: true }],
        access: [{ type: String, required: true }]
    },
    { versionKey: false }
);
```

In a mongodb query, I need to retrieve one user with a role and permission?

MongoDB is entirely new to me, but I have much experience with SQL databases. I have tried with the populate option but it is not retrieving permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your `UserSchema` as:

```
const UserSchema: Schema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  phone: { countryCode: { type: String }, number: { type: String } },
  role: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Role' },
});
```

And `populate`:

```
const user = await User.findOne().populate('role').exec();
if (!user) return;
const permissions = user.role.permissions
```